# A problem with a simple PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

My task is to find a general solution to such a PDE: $xu_x+yu_y=0$.

My approach:

Such an equation is constant on its characteristics. So at first I want to find out what they look like. 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x} \implies y=Cx $$
Then I am not sure what to do? Should I show that $u(x,y)=f(y-Cx)$? But then $u(x,y)=f(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0$$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \ln|x|} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \ln|y|}=0$$
This draw us to change of variables : $X=\ln|x|$ and $Y=\ln|y|$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial Y}=0$$
I suppose that you know how to continue.

Comment: Hmm... can't I use the method of characteristics at the beginning? Was my approach bad? This was the only method so far shown during the course...

Comment: The method of characteristics is convenient as well. You obtained $\frac{y}{x}=C$. The genetal solution is $u(x,y)=f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$. This is consistent with the "direct" method $u(x,y)=F\left(\ln|y|-\ln|x|\right)$ : any functions $f()=F(\exp())$.